# How can I select a number and value from an enum in C#?

Tags: c#

I have just changed my code so that now it stores some data in an enum instead of in a SQL Server table.

Here's the enum:

```
public enum ContentTypes : int
{
    Article = 0,
    Menu = 1,
    ContentBlock = 3
}
```

I was running the following code:

```
        var contentTypes =
          (
              from contentType in this._contentTypeService.GetContentTypes()
              select new
              {
                  id = contentType.ContentTypeId,
                  name = contentType.Name
              }
          );
```

How can I change this so that instead of taking the data from the content service it just queries the enum to data for contentTypes?

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to do here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is this

```
var contentTypes =
    from value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ContentTypes)).Cast<int>()
    select new
    {
        id = value,
        name = Enum.GetName(typeof(ContentTypes), value)
    };
```

Comment: +1 btw I think you don't need to cast values to int - GetName accepts object

Comment: @lazyberezovsky `Enum.GetValues` returns an `Array`, so unfortunately you have to do a cast for C# to know what type `value` is.

Comment: Ah, see now. Yes, you are right. You also can use `from int value`

Comment: `GetValues` returns `ContentTypes[]`. You should cast to `ContentTypes` rather than `int`, for clearer code. (like Justin Pihony's answer)

Answer (score 3):

pswg might be right, but I am thinking you want [something like this](https://compilify.net/2sj)?

Here is code more direct to your question:

```
select new
{
    id = (int)contentType,
    name = contentType.ToString()
}
```

You can get the integer id simply by casting to an `int` and get the name of it by using its `ToString` (which may or may not be implicit here)